# Computer starts fine but has no display - intermittent

Tags: windows, graphics-card, display, motherboard, hdmi

My desktop computer is does the following randomly -- after long periods of working fine, months sometimes, turning on fine: Both HDMI and VGA refuse to send anything to the displays (different displays and cables make no difference in the 20+ times I've dealt with it). Usually I take all inputs from the slots on the computer while its power is switch off, holding the power button for 40 seconds and inserting only the display cable, turning the computer on again, which makes it output to the monitor again. This, or I leave it for a day or so and try the trick again.

Problem is, I have no idea how to pinpoint the problem and reliably fix it. This usually happens after a week or more of not using the computer, but it's not predictable...

Right now the issue has come back again, so I've used `Windows-Key` + `Enter` to put narrator on and logged on just fine, blindly. The problem is, I don't even know where to look for this problem, before figuring out how to do it blindly, if that's the best solution.

Just to clear up the last bit, which makes it even more confusing: when the display outputs correctly the computer itself works faultlessly (bar a really loud noise that I can only guess is the fan, whenever I sit at my menu of games such as Rocket League or Cities Skylines).

Please help me fix it, this has been a problem on and off with this computer for past 2 years.

**Computer Info**:
Advent DT3415 Desktop PC

- Type: Desktop PC
- Processor: Intel® Core™ i7-3770 Processor (3.90 GHz, 8MB cache)
- Operating system: Windows 10
- Storage: 2TB HDD, 7200rpm
- RAM: 8GB DDR3 (16GB maximum installable RAM)
- Graphics card: AMD Radeon HD 7770
- Graphics card memory: 1GB DDR5
- Motherboard: Customised ECS H61H2-MV
- Wireless: Ralink 802.11 b/g/n 150 Mbps USB dongle
- Ethernet: Gigabit Ethernet (10/100/1000)
- USB: USB 2.0 x 6
- Video interface: HDMI x 1; DisplayPort x 1; DVI-I Dual Link x 1; VGA
  x 1

Comment: Oh Gods, Advents are notorious for stuff like this. Do you have another graphics card to swap in just to check if that sorts it? Also, did you customise the motherboard yourself, or did it come like that. Do you know what the customisations were?

Comment: I honestly had no idea as I haven't dealt with many hardware issues before. Sadly no, I just have this one. It came like that, as I haven't modified a single thing inside it yet. I don't know what they were either cause it was a set from PC World ages ago

Comment: Does your motherboard have integrated graphics? Can you remove the graphics card and try it using the integrated graphics outputs?

Comment: It  does, Intel HD 4000. I removed the AMD card (I hadn't cleaned the insides of the computer in ages so it was really dusty) and plugged the HDMI into the motherboard slot, works fine. Now, any way to find out why it would give me a blank with the AMD card being used?

Comment: If it fails to display during boot then unfortunately it's unlikely to be a software issue. It really does sound like either your graphics card is broken or there's something wrong with the PCI slot. You'd probably be better off hoping it's the former, and it is more likely to be. The only other options I can think of are blowing on it to make sure there's no dust there, and making sure it's absolutely securely fastened into the socket (that the little lever is all the way in). You might also want to try switching out any cables you may have running to it from the power supply too.

Comment: Can one of those really be true if this problem has been happening on-and-off? It could work for long times without issue for it to only happen again some random chance so that's why I'm just unsure about those two things.

Comment: Yes, a hardware fault could be causing an intermittent issue, particularly if it's causing the card to not make the connection properly with the motherboard (damage to the graphics card pins, for example -- when you take all the cables out it may *jiggle* it, which could cause it to work for a short time). Also, if there is a power cable running to the graphics card and it's damaged, that could also cause an intermittent issue.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I've done a clean of the socket, and blew out all the dust from it and the PCI slots. It's all back in place and working now. If it does this all again I could try switching the cables it's using from its power supply, but I get the feeling I'll need to change both card and power supply if I want to upgrade from this card. What should I do now?

Comment: There's not really much you can do short of either waiting and hoping it doesn't reoccur or replacing the card. Good luck with it, though :).

Comment: That's fine then, I'm set for now at least. Thanks a lot, how could I say that you've helped me and it's solved since we're in the comments?

Comment: I'll post the last comment before it was fixed as an answer. Just a second...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try blowing on it to make sure there's no dust there, and making sure it's absolutely securely fastened into the socket (that the little lever is all the way in) -- taking it out and putting it back in again. You might also want to try switching out any cables you may have running to it from the power supply too.

A hardware fault could be causing the intermittent issue, particularly if it's causing the card to not make the connection properly with the motherboard (damage to the graphics card pins, for example -- when you take all the cables out it may jiggle it, which could cause it to work for a short time). Also, if there is a power cable running to the graphics card and it's damaged, that could also cause the intermittent issue.

Answer (score 0):

check power supply unit, it must be 500 watt at least, to feed up your graphic card, then update your graphic driver software with the latest version. inspect and clean GPU from dust, clean your windows os with CC Cleaner and see what happens, good luck